# The rounding bug is still here

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, numbers

As of right now, I have 21,650 reputation on Meta*:

[image]

As I understand it, this should be rounded *up* to 21.7k in post owner boxes. However, it's being rounded down:

[image]

Depriving me of like .2% of my hard-earned unicorn points is a travesty! Can we change this to how it used to work?

<sup>* oh crap what am I doing with my life?</sup>

Comment: I manually fixed your rounding error with my vote.

Comment: 21658 showing as 21.7k

Comment: Right @ShadowWizard - the issue is the behavior rounding at `##,#50` numbers

Comment: ಥ_ಥ <- me localizing numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, maybe all the issues around localized number display are actually fixed now.

## MAYBE

As of the last deploy rounding at halves should again perform as expected, instead of rounding towards evens.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a bug. From what I can see, Stack Exchange is applying [Round half to even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) rule:

> A tie-breaking rule that is less biased is round half to even, namely:
>
> - If the fraction of y is 0.5, then q is the even integer nearest to y.

As a proof, I just [found a user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/122080/damien-mathieu) who currently have exactly 15150 reputation points. Lo and behold!

> [image]

15150 is round to 15.2k as expected.

Comment: No, it's a bug.  We used to round to away from 0, my changes switched it to round towards even.  Fixing...

Comment: @Kevin haha, but you could use this as escape route, mark as [tag:status-bydesign] and be on your merry way. :-D